Auto-identification of abbreviations
I want to realize some function that will decrypt on-the-fly abbreviations based on a pre-trained dictionary. How do I do it in Python? For example, the phrase "The president of the U.S. visited N.Y. City" should be transformed to "The president of the United States visited New York City." Suppose the abbreviations are popular, and we don't know what they would be.
